# Recursive Function for Coin Change algorithm returning an empty list

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, collections, coin-change

I'm working on a recursive function which renders change in available combination of coins against a given quantity. The expected behavior is not achieved though in some cases.

For example: when the available coins are {9,5,3} and total is 21 or 30 for this set of coins, it returns an empty string.

```
public class ItemPacks{

    static int[] coinsAvailable = {9,5,3};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ItemPacks pack = new ItemPacks();

        System.out.println(pack.packageBreakDown(21)); //returns empty list
        //or
        System.out.println(pack.packageBreakDown(30)); //returns empty list
    }

    public List<Integer> packageBreakDown(int amount) {
        return calculateBreakdown(amount, new ArrayList<>(), 0);
    }


    private List<Integer> calculateBreakdown(int quantity,List<Integer> coins, int pos) {

        if (pos < 0 || pos >= coinsAvailable.length) { // check if position is invalid
            return new ArrayList<>(); // return an empty list
        }

        if (quantity == coinsAvailable[pos]) { // check if quantity is equal to coinsAvailable[pos]
            coins.add(coinsAvailable[pos]); // add the coinsAvailable to the coins result
            return coins; // return the result
        } else if (quantity > coinsAvailable[pos]) { // check if quantity is greater than coinsAvailable[pos]
            coins.add(coinsAvailable[pos]);// add the possible coinsAvailable to the coins result
            quantity = quantity - coinsAvailable[pos]; // calculate the new quantity
            if (quantity >= coinsAvailable[pos]) { // check if quantity is greater than or equal to coinsAvailable[pos]
                return calculateBreakdown(quantity, coins, pos); // stick to this position
            } else {
                return calculateBreakdown(quantity, coins, pos + 1); // increment pos to go to the lower coinsAvailable
            }
        } else if (quantity < coinsAvailable[pos]) { // check if quantity is lesser than coinsAvailable[pos]
            if (coins.isEmpty()) { // if coins is empty then go to the next
                return calculateBreakdown(quantity, coins, pos + 1);
            } else {
                coins.remove(coins.size() - 1); // remove the previous
                return calculateBreakdown(quantity + coinsAvailable[pos - 1], coins, pos); // go back to the previous quantity and // try this coinsAvailable[pos]
            }
        }
        return coins;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `DENOMINATIONS.length` output , have you checked that ?

Comment: do you really needed recursive function? This problem is solvable by the dynamic programming, see my answer here fro closest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032242/how-can-i-find-elements-in-an-integer-array-that-add-up-to-k

Comment: @Ros5292: Sorry it was a typo.

Comment: There's a lot of missing information here and the formatting is difficult to follow. Can you produce a [mcve]? What are `remaining`, `ItemPacks` and `change`, for example? `quantity` is unused. I suggest running your code with `javac`.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry. I've fixed the missing info and edited the code.